# Adding image objects dynamically in qml

Tags: c++, dynamic, qml

I have main.cpp in which I want to call a C++ function to create image objects in QML during run time. How to add image objects in QML dynamically based on the input given in C++ function?

Comment: Though it is old and for QtQuick 1.1, this might help you as an *inspirational* source: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/02/29/qt-commercial-support-weekly-15-models-providing-dynamic-images-in-qml-2/

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`ImageProvider`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) to provide the source for the `Image`-objects. Then you expose a C++ model to QML, that contains the identifiers for the `ImageProvider`.

Finally you use a `Repeater`/`ListView`/`GridView`... to instantiate `Image`-objects (`delegate`) and set the source to the `modelData`, so it loads the image from the `ImageProvider`

Comment: Thank you so much, But I am really really new to this. Can anyone please give me a sample example so that I can continue from that? I have been trying this day and night for 3 straight days still I am not able to do it.

Comment: It would take me some time, so I need to see, when I find this. I can't promise it.